# Remove css inline class and style from a specific td

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I have a kendo Grid which is generating below code:

```
<div id="myGrid" class="k-grid k-widget" data-role="grid" style="display: block;">
   <div class="k-grid-header" style="padding-right: 17px;">
     <div class="k-grid-header-wrap">
       <table role="grid">
          <colgroup>
             <col>
          </colgroup>
          <thead role="rowgroup">
            <tr role="row">
               <th role="columnheader" data-field="filename" rowspan="1" data-title="Nombre" data-index="0" id="9d93448e-a9f6-42bd-8ba6-c8b31334efcc" class="k-header">Name</th>
               <th id="1b52a29e-730e-471c-978f-a44cffad7d90" rowspan="1" data-index="1" class="k-header">/th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
       </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="k-grid-content">
    <table role="grid">
      <colgroup>
        <col>
      </colgroup>
      <tbody role="rowgroup">
        <tr data-uid="368518f3-0ffc-4797-b262-85346e89430e" role="row">
          <td class="text-disabled-color" role="gridcell">
            <a href="javascript:" onclick="onOpenFile(&quot;/myController/myAction/OpenAttachmentById&quot;,&quot;9286f5c9-447b-4fb5-b322-0d5bf09d1913&quot;)">myFile.pdf</a>
          </td>
          <td style="display:none" role="gridcell">
            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-delete" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
```

From the second table only, I would like to remove the two following inline class and css style from the td elements:

```
class="text-disabled-color"
style="display:none"
```

I know I can do that by using jQuery:

```
$("td[class='text-disabled-color']").removeAttr("class");​
$("td[style='display:none']").removeAttr("style");​
```

However this is a bit dangerous because if another td element has this same inline class and style it will get removed.

I want to remove the inline class and style from the second table within the div container myGrid. Imagine there is another table with td elements with the same inline class and style, in that case I do not want to remove them, only those within myGrid container. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to remove that from second table always ?

Comment: @Swati yes, i need to remove them from only second table

Answer (score 3):

As you always need to remove second table `css` & `style` you can use `table:eq(1)` this will refer to second table i.e :

```
$("#myGrid table:eq(1) td.text-disabled-color").removeAttr('class')
$("#myGrid table:eq(1) td[style='display:none']").removeAttr("style");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of below script where find the table inside div with class k-grid-content. Find all tds within table and remove class / attribute.

```js
$(function(){
   var $table = $('#myGrid div.k-grid-content table[role=grid]');
   $table.find('td[role="gridcell"]').each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('text-disabled-color');
      $(this).removeAttr('style');
   });
});
```

```css
.text-disabled-color {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myGrid" class="k-grid k-widget" data-role="grid" style="display: block;">
   <div class="k-grid-header" style="padding-right: 17px;">
     <div class="k-grid-header-wrap">
       <table role="grid">
          <colgroup>
             <col>
          </colgroup>
          <thead role="rowgroup">
            <tr role="row">
               <th role="columnheader" data-field="filename" rowspan="1" data-title="Nombre" data-index="0" id="9d93448e-a9f6-42bd-8ba6-c8b31334efcc" class="k-header">Name</th>
               <th id="1b52a29e-730e-471c-978f-a44cffad7d90" rowspan="1" data-index="1" class="k-header"></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
       </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="k-grid-content">
    <table role="grid">
      <colgroup>
        <col>
      </colgroup>
      <tbody role="rowgroup">
        <tr data-uid="368518f3-0ffc-4797-b262-85346e89430e" role="row">
          <td class="text-disabled-color" role="gridcell">Some text
            <a href="javascript:" onclick="onOpenFile(&quot;/myController/myAction/OpenAttachmentById&quot;,&quot;9286f5c9-447b-4fb5-b322-0d5bf09d1913&quot;)">myFile.pdf</a>
          </td>
          <td style="display:none" role="gridcell">Some text
            <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-delete" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-delete"></span></a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
```